# Change font in singleemail messaging

Tags: email, email-template, apex-email-service, massemailmessage

I have below emailing code where I need to send mail in Callibri font. Can someone let me know a wayout here?

Code:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mailDM = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
sendTo.add(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).RepEmail_abv__c); 
mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
sendToDM.add(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).ManagerEmail_abv__c);
mailDM.setToAddresses(sendToDM);
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
mail.SetSaveAsActivity(false);
mailDM.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
mailDM.SetSaveAsActivity(false);
ccTo.add(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).ManagerEmail_abv__c);
mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);

mail.setTargetObjectId(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__c);
mailDM.setTargetObjectId(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__r.ManagerID);
mail.setSubject('Attention Required:  NEW ABS incident in iREP');
mailDM.setSubject('Action Required: NEW ABS incident in iREP');
String body = 'Dear ' + OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__r.Name + ', ';
body += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
body += '<br>New ABS Incidents have been generated in iREP. Please review these incidents with your DM or Applicable Manager. There is no other action for you to complete in iREP.';
body += '<br>To view your open incidents:<br>';
body += '•       Log into the iREP app on your iPad and select “Compliance Incidents”<br>';
body += '•       Select the “Open Incidents” View in the Compliance Incidents Home Page.<br>';
body += '•       Click the Incident ID to view your incidents If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.<br>';

String bodyDM = 'Dear ' +  OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__r.Manager.Name + ', ';
bodyDM += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
bodyDM += '<br>New ABS Incident(s) have been published in iREP.';
bodyDM += '<br>What you need to do:';
bodyDM += '<br>•       Review the incident(s)';
bodyDM += '<br>•       Coach your representative';
bodyDM += '<br>•       Attest to the incident, submit, and sync iREP within two weeks, per ABS policy';
bodyDM += '<br>If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.';

mail.setHtmlBody(body);
mails.add(mail);
mailDM.setHtmlBody(bodyDM);
mailsDM.add(mailDM);
system.debug('@mails@'+mails);

}
// Step 6: Send all emails in the master list*/
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
Messaging.sendEmail(mailsDM);
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Successfully Published'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the construction of the body of your email and enclose the entire message within the paragraph tags:

`<p style="font-family:Calibri"> [your email body here]</p>`.

Apex code:

```
  body = '<p style="font-family:Calibri">' + body + '</p>';
```

You may also want to checkout the HTML and CSS tutorials at [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

Comment: Can I put string mail body in your tag above as [mail body]?

Comment: [your email body here] is meant to indicate where you would put your email body.  You still need to use apex to do the string contatentation to build the email body

Comment: mail.setHtmlBody(<p style="font-family:Calibri"> body</p>);     I am getting error by putting it like this. Can you please help?